# Implementing Borland's __emit__ macro in GCC

Tags: c++, assembly, gcc

In Borland, there is a macro `__emit__`, "a pseudo-function that injects literal values directly into the object code" ([James Holderness](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2334192/james-holderness)).

Is there an equivalent for gcc / g++?
(I can't seem to find one in the documentation)

If not, how could I implement it in my C++ source code?

---

Usage can be found at [Metamorphic Code Examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10113254/metamorphic-code-examples)

Comment: Can't you just use inline assembly?

Comment: `#define __emit__(...) asm __volatile__ (".byte " #__VA_ARGS__)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can take a look at [`.byte`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7290318/3235496) assembler directive:

```
asm __volatile__ (".byte 0xEA, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0xFF");
```

GCC's optimizers sometimes discard `asm` statements if they determine there is no need for the output variables. Also, the optimizers may move code out of loops if they believe that the code will always return the same result (i.e. none of its input values change between calls). [Using the volatile qualifier disables these optimizations](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html#Volatile).

Anyway you should pay attention to many corner cases (e.g. [gcc skips asm code after goto](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22533187/3235496)...)